# edit privileges not showing

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

The Action column of the PhpMyAdmin is not displaying the Edit Privileges. I did not get the solution for this problem. I even tried to upgrade and degrade the PhpMyAdmin version, but nothing worked. I have attached a screenshot of PhpMyAdmin for verification. Please verify it and give me the solution to this problem.

Operating System: Windows 10, Php Version : 7.2.34,

Comment: *The Action column of the PhpMyAdmin is not displaying the Edit Privileges.* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html#grant-privileges There is no such privilege in MySQL. Do you mean UPDATE privilege?

Comment: What MySQL version do you have? What are the `show grants` for the MySQL user PhpMyAdmin connects as?